# Commands separated by pipe | character, how to execute them separately?

Tags: command-line, elasticsearch

The following two commands are separated by a pipe `|` character, which means they will be executed together, in one go:

```
wget -qO - https://artifacts.elastic.co/GPG-KEY-elasticsearch | sudo apt-key add -
```

I need to run them separately, as two commands.

Actually these commands download and install the public signing key for elastic search.

But for some reason, they are giving me

```
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
```

My web search tells me that executing both the commands separately *might* solve my problem. So I am trying to do that.

So the first command `wget -qO - https://artifacts.elastic.co/GPG-KEY-elasticsearch` returns fine, while the second one `sudo apt-key add -` goes forever, and never returns.

Comment: `-` means use STDIN as input (ie the STDOUT of the command before the pipe). You need to give the key, if you are not piping to the command.

Comment: @Zanna Is there a way to somehow assign the key obtained as a result of 1st command to some kind of variable, and then use that variable in the second command?

Comment: yes, do `mykey=$(wget -qO - https://artifacts.elastic.co/GPG-KEY-elasticsearch)`

Comment: @George and then do `sudo apt-key add $mykey` in the second command right?

Comment: See my answer below and just tested it

Comment: I think the problem is not the pipe, but the key. Get the right key and it will work!

Comment: @Zanna I added that key on my end and it's ok.

Comment: @George ok, good that it works for you, but I still think the syntax is not the real issue here - this is an established method...

Comment: @Zanna I agree with on that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First run:

```
wget -qO - https://artifacts.elastic.co/GPG-KEY-elasticsearch -O mykey
```

Then run:

```
sudo apt-key add <<< mykey
```

Comment: The second one still gives me `gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.`

Comment: But this means the method to run those commands separately is correct, which answers this question. So thank you.